# Sort array values by specific order given in another array

Tags: php, arrays, asort, instruction-reordering

I have this array that is the correct order:

```
$orderDoc = array("ORT", "TRI", "CONT", "RMI");
```

These documents are in different tables of several servers and database.
At the end of doing the search of the documents I usually get an array with the following structure but with the elements in disarray:

//simulated variable:

```
$FindDoc= array("RMI0000191","ORT0000379","ORT0000391","ORT0000392","ORT0000390","CONT0000274","CONT0000275","RMI0000192","ORT0000391");
```

Ouput:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000191"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000379"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000391"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000392"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000390"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000274"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000275"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000192"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000394"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "TRI0000170"
}
```

I try to use this but it doesn't work. I get an error because the second parameter need to be integer:

```
$FindDoc=asort($FindDoc,$orderDoc );
```

After investigate none of this native function work:

```
PHP - Sort Functions For Arrays
In this chapter, we will go through the following PHP array sort functions:

sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

**How can I get the proper order of values?**

Example of what was expected, order by $orderDoc ordes and By numeric Document:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000379"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000390"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000391"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000392"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000394"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "TRI0000170"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000274"
  [7]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000275"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000191"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000192"
}
```

**Update I try to use a custom function but get the somes error's:**

```
foreach ($FindDoc as $StructureMember) {
    $key = array_search($StructureMember, function ($StructureMember, $orderDoc ) {
        return (strpos($StructureMember, $orderDoc ));
    });
    $result[$key] = $StructureMember;
}
$FindDoc = $result;
```

output:

```
Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\class\class.docinfo.php on line 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the orderdoc and use preg_grep to get all array items that start with the same characters.
Then sort the array that is returned and merge them in to the result array.

```
$orderDoc = array("ORT", "TRI", "CONT", "RMI");

$FindDoc= array("RMI0000191","ORT0000379","ORT0000391","ORT0000392","ORT0000390","CONT0000274","CONT0000275","RMI0000192","ORT0000391");

$result =[];
foreach($orderDoc as $doc){
    $temp = preg_grep("/^". preg_quote($doc) . "/", $FindDoc);
    sort($temp);
    $result = array_merge($result, $temp);
}

var_dump($result);
```

$result:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000379"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000390"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000391"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000391"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "ORT0000392"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000274"
  [6]=>
  string(11) "CONT0000275"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000191"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "RMI0000192"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/eqUBv

Notice: this preserves the duplicates from your array.
You don't say that they should be removed but if you want them removed just add a array_unique() before temp is merged in the $result

Comment: no problem with duplicate i have prevent it on mysql query that generated $FindDoc.